# how to make a user act as a seller and as a buyer at the same time in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I have a scenario in which I want to sign up a user but I need the user to be signed up as a seller and as a buyer at the same time after signing up.
and that user can sell and purchase the products without logging out or logging as a buyer or seller separately.

I know an approach to do it by using tuples but it is not a suitable solution for my problem and it is given below:

```
class User(models.Model):
    USER_ROLES = (
                 ('SELLER', 'Seller'),
                 ('Buyer', 'Buyer'),
                  )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = USER_ROLES)
```

I am also thinking to do it this way:

```
class User(models.Model):
        USER_ROLES = (
                     ('BOTH_USERS', 'Seller Buyer'),
                      )
        user_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = USER_ROLES)
```

I am not sure how to do it. can any of you help me, please?

I hope it makes some sense that what I want as a result.

Comment: Can a user be only a seller and not a buyer and vice-versa? Can a user be neither?

Comment: I mean the new user should act as both seller and buyer.

Comment: Are there other user types? You could just have two BooleanFields `is_buyer` and `is_seller` instead, set both to True for your new user

Comment: the other user is super user. which can be handled very easily. the problem is how to make two user types in a single sign up

Comment: using is_buyer and is_seller would not solve my issue. and I think you understand it as well.

Comment: if I set them true in a boolean field then will it work as a seller and as a buyer at the same time? and will the user be able to sell and buy the things?

Comment: I don't see how it wouldn't solve your issue. The two flags/types are not mutually exclusive so it does not make sense to have a single field. Just check the boolean flags to see if the user is allowed to buy or sell

Comment: are you trying to say that I make two different bool fields, set them false and when I sign up the user, I set those bool fields to true using create method? right?

Comment: Aren't [Django permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/) cater for this exact case? A user can be related with many groups.

Comment: yes, I am thinking the same way now. creating 2 groups and then add permissions of buy and sell. but not sure how to use permission while signing up

Answer (score 1):

Django Authentication System provides the ability to delegate users into groups with permissions.

The admin interface tackles with this [very smoothly](https://djangobook.com/django-tutorials/mastering-django-admin/)

You can, of course, achieve the same result [programmatically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

Then, in your view, you can check if the logged in user [has permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) to add a new object in the models `SellProduct` and `BuyProduct` of the application `marketplace`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def create_sale_view(request):
    if request.user.has_perm(
        "marketplace.add_sellproduct"
    ) and request.user.has_perm("marketplace.add_buyproduct"):
        # The user can buy and sell
        pass
    else:
        # The user cannot buy nor sell
        pass
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable time. according to this approach, a user can only sell or buy only. I want a user to sell and buy the products. will your logic do the same things?

Comment: @djangodeveloper This is just an example. I modified it to cater for both permissions in the same application. However, this is a matter of database design.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_seller = models.BooleanField(default = False)

class Customer(models.Model):
    buyer = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    address  = models.TextField()

class Seller(models.Model):
    seller = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    store = models.CharField(max_length = 90)
```

You can use this approach and block the customer or seller's access using decorators. I've used this method to build my website.

Comment: Hi @Dhiman thanks for your answer. my question is, how a user can sell and buy the things with this approach? I am confused.

Comment: Do you want the website to have functionality like eBay?

Comment: A single  user acting both as a seller and a buyer.

Comment: yes like eBay. you got the point. On eBay, a logged-in user can click on sell and the user will act as a seller. and the same time that user will also be able to but the things

Comment: yes. a user must act as a seller and a buyer at the same time.

Comment: I don't think you need user types for that. You can create a single user model and connect it with other models using ForeignKey

Comment: so I need to have two more models seller and buyer and make a relation of foreign key? so what should the data type of the object/field in the user model be to make it act as both user types?

Comment: No,  that's not what I mean to say

Comment: can we have a chat in chat provided by the stackover flow?

Comment: I couldn't create ebay functionality with this logic.